Rolify and Resourcify for User STI in Rails
I have User STI for Administrator & Employee model and uses rolify and resoucify with the below logic
consider that I have installed Rolify correctly
class User < ApplicationRecord
  
end

class Administrator < User
  rolify
  has_many :employees, -> { where(roles: { name: :admin }) }, through: :roles, source: :resource, source_type: :Employee
end

class Employee < User
  resourcify
  has_many :administrators, -> { distinct }, through: :roles, class_name: 'User', source: :users
  has_many :admins, -> { where(roles: { name: :admin }) }, through: :roles, source: :administrators
end

If I try in console employees works fine for me
Administrator.last.employees
[#<Employee id: 789, email: "test11@example.com", created_at: "2024-11-19 11:55:43.251636000 +0530", updated_at: "2024-11-19 11:55:43.251636000 +0530", is_active: true,...

> Employee.find(789).administrators
[]


above Employee.find(789).administrators is always empty
Why the above design?
Answer: Employee record is resource of administrators,
administrators can be with any role like team_leader, accountant, HR or any other

The combination of Rolify and having multiple STI user classes feels totally backwards. The whole point of having roles is that the roles assigned to a user define if its and admin, employer etc. and in what scope. You're just making the pattern less flexible as you're locking the user into a single role and making Rolify redundant.

Also when it comes to the employee -> employer relationship you might want to create a designated employments table so that you can keep track of things like the employment dates, what position an employee occupies etc.

The employee is a resource of Administrator, and Administrator can have multiple roles like team leader, accountant, HR for this above design is good, can I resourcify and rolify the same model record?

You can but it might not be the best solution for a complex domain as you're basically making the Role class into a god class and stringing your whole app together through a single polymorphic join table.

For the above case, I request you to suggest a structure that will be suitable for me.

I can't actually do that as I don't know what your buisness requirements are and it's also way too big of an ask. I politly decline.
